# MySQL - Recuperar registros de una tabla en atención a columna JSON de otra tabla

Tags: mysql, json

Tengo una tabla llamada **tabla1** que contiene una columna tipo jSON llamada **columnaJSON** que guarda IDs así: `[1,3,5,7]`

La idea es armar una consulta que recupere todos los registros de una **tabla2** siempre y cuando los IDs de los registros de esta "tabla2" correspondan con los IDs hallados en en la columna jSON de la "tabla1".

Obviamente lo que sigue no funciona, pero muestra lo que deseo hacer.

```
SELECT `t2`.`id`, `t2`.`nombre`
FROM `tabla1` AS `t1`
JOIN `tabla2` AS `t2`
ON `t2`.`id` JSON_IN `t1`.`columnaJSON`
WHERE `t1`.`publicado` = 1;
```

Gracias de antemano por cualquier sugerencia de cómo proceder.

Comment: Se que es medio tarde, pero si ya tenes este tipo de problemas, te recomiendo empezar a [normalizar tus tablas](https://cnx.org/contents/qtZsLi-X@1/Un-ejemplo-simple-de-normalizaci%C3%B3n-de-bases-de-datos-relacionales-hasta-3FN)

Answer (score 0):

A partir de MySQL 8+ podes usar [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.id, t2.nombre
    FROM tabla1 AS t1
    CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
        t1.columnaJSON, "$[*]" COLUMNS( value INT PATH "$")
    ) d
    INNER JOIN tabla2 AS t2
        ON t2.id = d.value
    WHERE t1.publicado = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e9aoq6cgfFpsGhryKxoU1b/0)</kbd>